# Is there a built-in way to match ranges of values against ranges of values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a value somewhere in a list items, whose value is a range from `3-10`.

Then let's say I search using a range from say `5-15`.

Since the lower end of the search range (`5`) falls within the range of the entry in the list (`3-10`), then it should match.

To do this I have to check if either range value in the search falls between the range values of the entry, and vice-verse.

While I have a working function for this, I was wondering if there is a common pattern or built-in way to do this kind of "range matrix" filtering in JavaScript. I don't even know if there is some actual nomenclature for this sort of thing.

Expected behavior: https://repl.it/Jz6c/0

Comment: can u post input and expected output ??

Comment: No, there isn't AFAIK...

Comment: how is the search range declared? as a minimum and maximum, or is it a list of valid values? are you dealing with integers only?

Comment: *While I have a working function for this [...]* Why not add it to your question? It's like Fermat's last theorem: *I have discovered a truly marvelous proof of this, which this margin is too narrow to contain*. And then he leaves mathematicians wondering for 300 years.

Comment: Whats wrong with Math.max and Math.min ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is more of a [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) question than a Stack Overflow question, but since we're here...

Based on [your repl.it demo](https://repl.it/Jz6c/0), it looks like you are asking if there is a simpler way to write this code:

```
var matchesRange = function(min, max, value) {
  return value >= min && value <= max;
};

var matchesRangeMatrix = function(searchRange, targetRange) {
  return matchesRange(searchRange.min, searchRange.max, targetRange.min) ||
    matchesRange(searchRange.min, searchRange.max, targetRange.max) ||
    matchesRange(targetRange.min, targetRange.max, searchRange.min) ||
    matchesRange(targetRange.min, targetRange.max, searchRange.max);
};
```

where you call `matchesRangeMatrix()` with two object arguments, each of which has a `min` and `max` property.

This code makes a total of eight comparisons (four calls to `matchesRange` with two comparisons each).

You can do the whole thing with only two comparisons. Let's take out the `matrix` nomenclature, since that seems to make it sound more complicated than it is. Instead, how about a function called `rangesOverlap()`:

```
function rangesOverlap( one, two ) {
    return one.min < two.max && two.min < one.max;
}
```

That's all you need! Try this [updated version of your repl.it](https://repl.it/Jz6c/1) and compare the results with your original.

If you're wondering how something so simple could work, I invite you to read [this Hacker News discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14638577) where I and a few other people debated this very topic. (I'm "Stratoscope" over there, but in particular look for a comment by "barrkel" about a third of the way down the page that lists a truth table for this problem.)

The context of that discussion was whether two appointments conflict or not. For example, appointments from 1-2pm and 2-3pm would *not* conflict even though the first one ends at the same time the second one begins. If your definition of overlapping ranges is different, so 1-2 and 2-3 would be considered to overlap, you should be able to do this by using `<=` instead of `<`:

```
function rangesOverlap( one, two ) {
    return one.min <= two.max && two.min <= one.max;
}
```

But fair warning, I have not tested this version of the code.

Note that this isn't anything specific to JavaScript. The same question and the same solutions would apply to pretty much any programming language.